# Additional property to extended Error class

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using nodejs with typescript. In response on my frontend in addition to status and message of error I want to add one extra property, I have a custom class error handler extending Error type.

```
export class ApiError extends Error {
  status: number;

  constructor(status: number, msg: string) {

    super(msg);
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    this.status = status;
  }
}
```

i.e. user not found error in frontend's console in data object is following

```
data: {
   message: "User wasn't found", //msg argument in constructor
   status: 404, //status argument in constructor
}
```

I want add to these properties my custom property, how can i do this?

Comment: What did you get?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you can add additional properties to your custom ApiError class by simply adding it to the constructor

eg: if you want to add a name property you would do the following

```
export class ApiError extends Error {
  status: number;

  constructor(status: number, msg: string, name: string) {

    super(msg);
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    this.status = status;

    this.name = name;
  }
}
```